# How to keep exchange emails from showing up in contacts? (iOS7)

Tags: iphone, contacts, exchange

After upgrading an iPhone user from iOS6 to 7, I'm having an issue where, in my contacts app, all 2000 email address from my exchange account are showing up in my contacts.

If I go under settings and turn off the contacts tab under the exchange servers. It just deletes all contacts from my phone. Including ones that aren't emails.

How do I get rid of them so that the phone only shows the contacts that are stored on the phone and not synced from exchange?

Comment: If I go under settings and turn off the contacts tab under the exchange servers. It just deletes all contacts from my phone. Including ones that aren't emails.

Comment: So you want the Contacts app only to show those exchange contacts that have a phone number to be shown.

Answer (score 1):

You can add all the contacts you want to show up in contacts in a group named "visible" and all the others to an "invisible" group. Then in contacts on the upper left there is an option to select which groups you want to be visible. Just select the "visible" one.

[image: Group Selection]